# CSS3, multiple sliders will only display 1 main image at a time

Tags: html, css, slider, responsive

Let me start off by stating I'm an absolute noob at webdesign and I mostly just use it for my game art portfolio. I'm somewhat familiar with HTML and CSS3 but that's where my coding skill pretty much end abrubtly.

I wanted a nice simple slider with thumbnails for my portfolio, and I found [this one](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-image-slider-with-stylized-thumbnails) online and it seems to work for me for the most part.

I want to be able to duplicate this slider on my web page so I can dedicate an entire slider for each project I have and fill it with images.

However this slider doesn't allow me to do that. When I duplicate it, it only displays 1 main image corresponding to the clicked thumbnail at a time.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="project2">

        <!-- Project slider -->
        <div class="p-slider">
            <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id1"/>
            <label for="id1">
                <img src="images/content/3D/turtleneck_staf_2.jpg"/>
            </label>
            <img src="images/content/3D/turtleneck_staf_2.jpg"/>

            <!--Lets show the second image by default on page load-->
            <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id2" checked="checked"/>
            <label for="id2">
                <img src="images/content/3D/turtleneck_staf_1.jpg"/>
            </label>
            <img src="images/content/3D/turtleneck_staf_1.jpg"/>

            <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id3"/>
            <label for="id3">
                <img src="images/content/3D/turtleneck_staf_3.jpg"/>
            </label>
            <img src="images/content/3D/turtleneck_staf_3.jpg"/>

            <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id4"/>
            <label for="id4">
                <img src="images/content/3D/turtleneck_staf_4.jpg"/>
            </label>
            <img src="images/content/3D/turtleneck_staf_4.jpg"/>

            <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id5"/>
            <label for="id5">
                <img src="images/content/3D/turtleneck_staf_5.jpg"/>
            </label>
            <img src="images/content/3D/turtleneck_staf_5.jpg"/>
        </div>

      </div>


      <div id="project3">

        <!-- Project slider -->
        <div class="p-slider">
            <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id6"/>
            <label for="id6">
                <img src="images/content/3D/keep_it_low_poly_2.jpg"/>
            </label>
            <img src="images/content/3D/keep_it_low_poly_2.jpg"/>

            <!--Lets show the second image by default on page load-->
            <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id7" checked="checked"/>
            <label for="id7">
                <img src="images/content/3D/keep_it_low_poly_1.jpg"/>
            </label>
            <img src="images/content/3D/keep_it_low_poly_1.jpg"/>

            <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id8"/>
            <label for="id8">
                <img src="images/content/3D/keep_it_low_poly_3.jpg"/>
            </label>
            <img src="images/content/3D/keep_it_low_poly_3.jpg"/>

            <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id9"/>
            <label for="id9">
                <img src="images/content/3D/keep_it_low_poly_4.jpg"/>
            </label>
            <img src="images/content/3D/keep_it_low_poly_4.jpg"/>

            <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id10"/>
            <label for="id10">
                <img src="images/content/3D/keep_it_low_poly_5.jpg"/>
            </label>
            <img src="images/content/3D/keep_it_low_poly_5.jpg"/>
        </div>

      </div>
```

Each slider is embedded in its own "project" div because I wanted to have each project to have a slightly different background color.

Then I ofcourse also have a CSS sheet that both sliders are linked to:

```
.p-slider{
width: 83%; 
position: relative;
padding-top: 41.8%; 
margin: 20px auto;
margin-bottom: 150px;
box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.content .p-slider>img{
position: absolute;
left: 0; top: 0;
transition: all 0.5s;
width:100%;
}

.p-slider input[name='slide_switch'] {
display: none;
}

.p-slider label {
margin: 18px 0 0 18px;
border: 3px solid #999;
float: left;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 0.5s;
opacity: 0.6;
}

.p-slider label img{
display: block;
width: 200px;   
}

.p-slider input[name='slide_switch']:checked+label {
border-color: #666;
opacity: 1;
}

.p-slider input[name='slide_switch'] ~ img {
opacity: 0;
transform: scale(1.1);
}

.p-slider input[name='slide_switch']:checked+label+img {
opacity: 1;
transform: scale(1);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

.p-slider label img{
/*display: block;*/
width: 100px;
}

}
```

Try to ignore the funky percentages, that's because the images I was using have a weird aspect ratio (1920 x 966), more on that below.

So that's the first problem. I have 2 sliders, and at any time when I click a thumbnail only 1 of them will display a main image. I want to be able to copy it dozens of times and have each slider display a corresponding main image.

My second problem is that fact that this slider wasn't really responsive when I found it. I partially solved it by using percentages instead of pixels, but I don't really know how to apply this to the thumbnails.

The web page needs to be able to be viewed on mobile devices aswell, thus this is an important feature.

And yes I realize that there are probably better and smarter ways of creating a responsive CSS slider, but like I said, I'm a total noob. This works for me.

Comment: Its better and easy using  [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and then use a [snippcode](http://bootsnipp.com/tags/carousel?page=3) did you tried bootstrap?

Comment: I guess that's an option but I'd really like a solution for this. Besides I don't really do Javascript because I don't know Javascript. And I've already ran into problems with conflicting libraries in the past whilst trying out other sliders with Javascript. 

This one doesn't use any Javascript, therefore it suits me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use same name "slide_switch" for all inputs. It groups them together, so only one of them could be checked. You have to use different name for every project.

Comment: Thank you! That sort of solved my first problem. There isn't a way to do this without having to change the name for the inputs on each slider?

Comment: The way your slider is workig, you have to use different name attributes. But you can edit your CSS to use class instead of name, so you don't have to write css for every slider. IN CSS: input.slide_switch{} in HTML: <input type="radio" class="slide_switch" name="somename" id="id5"/>

Comment: I changed all the "name=" tags with "class=" tags in my HTML and CSS but it doens't seem to be working correctly. Am I still missing something?

Comment: Look there to this link http://jsfiddle.net/txzg4s72/ images are not visible, but it's working. I guess you forgot to write "name" to inputs.

Comment: Thank you again! Seems to work like a charm now. Although I don't quite understand why the inputs need "name=" tags if they aren't used for anything in the CSS. But thank you for helping out a newbie regardless! And you were right in your first response btw, I looked over that part.

Comment: Just some clarification for you since you are new to this: Classes are used to add styles to your html. Names can be used for adding styles too, but their main purporse is adding "function" to your code. It's not actually that way, but for you it could be more understandable in this words :) Giving a name to Inputs with type Radio you actually say - from all inputs with same name, you can check only one of them = only one big image could be visible (because in your code only "checked" images are visible as big images).

Comment: If you use same name for all inputs across whole site = you can check only one from whole site. If you use no name for inputs = inputs won't be in groups and you can basicly have every input checked. It's little advance part of html, you can look at some tutorials on how to make web form, there should be more explanations.

Comment: I will try to keep that in mind for next time. Although I'm not planning on becoming a master coder, my focus is becoming a game artist. But its always cool to learn new things!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
<ul class="s-thumbs">
    <li><a href="#slide-1"><img src="img/thumb1.png" alt="" /><span>Image 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide-2"><img src="img/thumb2.png" alt="" /><span>Image 2</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide-3"><img src="img/thumb3.png" alt="" /><span>Image 3</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide-4"><img src="img/thumb4.png" alt="" /><span>Image 4</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide-5"><img src="img/thumb5.png" alt="" /><span>Image 5</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide-6"><img src="img/thumb6.png" alt="" /><span>Image 6</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide-7"><img src="img/thumb7.png" alt="" /><span>Image 7</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div><ul class="s-slides">
    <li id="slide-1" class="slideLeft"><img src="img/slide1.png" alt="" /></li>
    <li id="slide-2" class="slideRight"><img src="img/slide2.png" alt="" /></li>
    <li id="slide-3" class="slideTop"><img src="img/slide3.png" alt="" /></li>
    <li id="slide-4" class="slideBottom"><img src="img/slide4.png" alt="" /></li>
    <li id="slide-5" class="zoomIn"><img src="img/slide5.png" alt="" /></li>
    <li id="slide-6" class="zoomOut"><img src="img/slide6.png" alt="" /></li>
    <li id="slide-7" class="rotate"><img src="img/slide7.png" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I only give you HTML code & in this link you can check CSS code. So by using css you can make slide or you can change as you want.

**Please check this link:-http://designmodo.com/slider-css3/ & https://www.sanwebe.com/2012/08/pure-css3-tutorials-examples**

Comment: That one looks nice. But I can't get it working very quickly at this time. If nobody can help me with my original slider I'll try this one.

Thank you nevertheless.